# yocto build libiberty.h missing for linux 5.10

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake, binutils

We are using yocto-sumo and trying to update our current linux 4.19.1 to 5.10 for various reasons, I've created a new defconfig and updated the linux-recipe. Using bitbake gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: linux-apa-4.19.1-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: linux-apa-4.19.1-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work/vit-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0/temp/log.do_compile.52260)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work/vit-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0/temp/log.do_compile.52260
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot
| NOTE: Direct dependencies are ['virtual:native:/home/dev/apa/master/os/src/poky/meta/recipes-support/lzop/lzop_1.03.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/dev/apa/master/os/src/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/quilt/quilt-native_0.65.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/dev/apa/master/os/src/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/bison/bison_3.0.4.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/dev/apa/master/os/src/poky/meta/recipes-extended/bc/bc_1.06.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/dev/apa/master/os/src/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/binutils/binutils-cross_2.30.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/dev/apa/master/os/src/poky/meta/recipes-kernel/kmod/kmod-native_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/dev/apa/master/os/src/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross_7.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot']
| NOTE: Installed into sysroot: []
| NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: ['lzop-native', 'quilt-native', 'bison-native', 'bc-native', 'binutils-cross-arm', 'kmod-native', 'gcc-cross-arm', 'libtool-native', 'automake-native', 'gnu-config-native', 'autoconf-native', 'lzo-native', 'flex-native', 'texinfo-dummy-native', 'xz-native', 'glibc', 'libmpc-native', 'linux-libc-headers', 'mpfr-native', 'zlib-native', 'gmp-native', 'gettext-minimal-native', 'gtk-doc-native', 'pkgconfig-native', 'python3-native', 'm4-native', 'readline-native', 'sqlite3-native', 'gdbm-native', 'bzip2-native', 'openssl-native', 'ncurses-native', 'cryptodev-linux-native', 'makedepend-native', 'xproto-native', 'util-macros-native']
| DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j4 HOSTCC=gcc  -isystem/home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work/vit-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -L/home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work/vit-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib -L/home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work/vit-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work/vit-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work/vit-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work/vit-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work/vit-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib -Wl,-O1 HOSTCPP=gcc  -E zImage CC=arm-agbrain-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mno-thumb-interwork -marm -fuse-ld=bfd -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work/vit-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0=/usr/src/debug/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work/vit-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0/recipe-sysroot= -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work/vit-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native=  -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work-shared/vit/kernel-source=/usr/src/kernel -ffile-prefix-map=/home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work/vit-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0/git=/kernel-source/  LD=arm-agbrain-linux-gnueabi-ld.bfd   LOADADDR=0x10008000
|   GEN     Makefile
|   HOSTCXX scripts/gcc-plugins/arm_ssp_per_task_plugin.so
| In file included from /home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work/vit-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/../../lib/arm-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/7.3.0/plugin/include/gcc-plugin.h:28:0,
|                  from /home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work-shared/vit/kernel-source/scripts/gcc-plugins/gcc-common.h:7,
|                  from /home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work-shared/vit/kernel-source/scripts/gcc-plugins/arm_ssp_per_task_plugin.c:3:
| /home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work/vit-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/../../lib/arm-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/7.3.0/plugin/include/system.h:691:10: fatal error: libiberty.h: No such file or directory
|  #include "libiberty.h"
|           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
| compilation terminated.
| /home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work-shared/vit/kernel-source/scripts/gcc-plugins/Makefile:48: recipe for target 'scripts/gcc-plugins/arm_ssp_per_task_plugin.so' failed
| make[3]: *** [scripts/gcc-plugins/arm_ssp_per_task_plugin.so] Error 1
| /home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work-shared/vit/kernel-source/scripts/Makefile.build:514: recipe for target 'scripts/gcc-plugins' failed
| make[2]: *** [scripts/gcc-plugins] Error 2
| /home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work-shared/vit/kernel-source/Makefile:1196: recipe for target 'scripts' failed
| make[1]: *** [scripts] Error 2
| /home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work-shared/vit/kernel-source/Makefile:220: recipe for target '__sub-make' failed
| make: *** [__sub-make] Error 2
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work/vit-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0/temp/log.do_compile.52260)
ERROR: Task (/home/dev/apa/master/os/src/meta-apa-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-apa_4.19.1.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
```

Looking into `workdir/recipe-sysroot-native` folder shows that the header is available

```
dev@ubuntu:~/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work/vit-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include$ ll | grep libiberty
drwxrwxr-x  2 dev dev   4096 Jul 14 11:20 libiberty/
-rw-r--r--  9 dev dev  27266 Jul 14 10:40 libiberty.h
```

and the bitbake-log tells me, the folder is also included properly

```
make -j4 HOSTCC=gcc  -isystem/home/dev/apa/master/os/build_release/tmp/work/vit-agbrain-linux-gnueabi/linux-apa/4.19.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Hint : `libiberty.h` is provided by "gcc-X-plugin-dev"   https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=libiberty.h

Comment: binutils builds and installs libiberty.h from what I can tell. 
`do_install_class-native () {`
`autotools_do_install`
`# Install the libiberty header`
`install -d ${D}${includedir}`
`install -m 644 ${S}/include/ansidecl.h ${D}${includedir}`
`install -m 644 ${S}/include/libiberty.h ${D}${includedir}`

Comment: You are right, libiberty.h is included in  binutils / "binutils-devel" for a number of OS. My bad showing some of the exceptions = Debian, Debian clones like Ubuntu.